# http-proxy hang up between ember-cli and node.js server

Tags: node.js, ember-cli, http-proxy

So I have an ember-cli based client application, and a separate node.js server which is acting as an API.  In order to send calls to the API, I use the incantation `ember serve --proxy http://localhost:6226/` when I start the client app.  However, approximately 1 out of 10 http calls ends up in the client application bombing out, like so:

```
/Users/me/Documents/Projects/banbury/node_modules/http-proxy/lib/http-proxy/index.js:119
throw err;
      ^
Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (http.js:1472:15)
    at Socket.socketCloseListener (http.js:1522:23)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at TCP.close (net.js:465:12)
```

Looking online, this seems to be related to the body-parser middleware [(see here)](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/925), but this only speaks in reference to mocking the api server with an ember-cli proxy (i.e. mock server on the client app that handles the api calls.)

My API is more mature than my client app, so I don't want to have to start duplicating effort by pulling the api across into the ember proxy, but I don't understand based on the link above what I need to do to either the ember-cli configuration, or my API server, to stop this from happening.  It's pretty much blocking my development because I can't trust the stability of my http requests.

Does anyone know what i'm missing in terms of my base configuration?  Do I need some extra proxy handling on the client-side in addition to the API server, or is this something that can be handled by the headers maybe?

Comment: Hello. I'm encountering the exact same problem. But only under Linux, not under Mac OS.  Any clue on this topic, since you posted the question? I'm gonna try and investigate some more... Thanks.